# Deleting a row with the smallest sum from NxN matrix in PHP

Tags: php, matrix

If the original matrix is

```
$input = [
    [123, 22, 33],
    [1, 2, 1],
    [82, 90, 12],
];
```

the output should look like this:

```
$expected = [
    [123, 22, 33],
    [82, 90, 12],
];
```

I tried to get minimum row through $min_row = $a[$i] and then comparing it in first for loop.

```php
function deleteRowWithSmallestSum($a){
    $N=sizeof($a);
    $M =sizeof($a);

    $mat = array();
    
   // $min_row =  $a[$i];

    for($i=0; $i<$N; $i++){
        $min_row =  $a[$i];
        
        if($a[$i]<$min_row){
            $a[$i] = $min_row;
           unset($a[$i]);
            
        }

        for($j=0; $j<$M; $j++){
            $mat[$i][$j] = $a[$i][$j];
        }
    }
    return $mat;



}
$a = [[455,1,2],
    [1,1,1],
    [11,222,3333]];

print_r($a);


deleteRowWithSmallestSum($a);
```

Comment: If the job is to delete the row with the lowest _sum_ of the numbers, then why am I not seeing you actually calculating any _sum_ anywhere here in the first place?

Comment: _Side note:_ Why are you calling `sizeof($a);` twice and store it in different variables? Just reuse the first variable instead (not that you actually need the inner loop at all if you use the above suggested array_sum())

Comment: The question is about NxN matrix and not 3x3, you want generic algorithm.

Comment: What if multiple rows have the same (minimal) sum?

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteRowWithSmallestSum($a){
    $lowest=-1;
    $lowVal=PHP_INT_MAX;
    foreach($a as $k=>$row) 
    {
       if(array_sum($row)<$lowVal) {
          $lowest= $k;
          $lowVal= array_sum($row);
       }
    }
    
    if($lowest!=-1) unset($a[$lowest]);
    return array_values($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteRowWithSmallestSum($a){
    $matrixSizeN = sizeof($a);
    if($matrixSizeN==0){
      return $a;
    }
 
    $minIndex = -1;
    if(sizeOf($a[0])!=$matrixSizeN){
        // Invalid matrix and do something
    }
    $minValue = $array_sum($a[0]);
    
    for($i=1; $i<$matrixSizeN; $i++){
        if(sizeOf($a[$i])!=$matrixSizeN){
        // Invalid matrix and do something
        }
        $tempValue = $array_sum($a[$i]);
        
        if($tempValue<$minValue){ // open issue about two lines with same minimum
        $minValue = $tempValue;
        $minIndex = $i;
        }
    }
    if($minIndex!=-1){
      unset($a[$minIndex]);
    }
    return array_values($a);
}
```